# Magento redirect error

Tags: checkout, error, redirect

For the past two months my site has been working well, but suddenly it does the following.

When I click the continue button in the checkout, the next page billing information appears and the if I try to enter the details it is redirected to shopping cart page.

My website can be found at http://callofthehorizon.com/

Comment: First question, what if anything has changed recently? Do you have any custom code in place.

Answer (score 3):

The ajax request that should refresh the checkout progress section has 500 header. So there is an internal server error. Check your server logs.
This is how Magento handles the a ajax requests on the checkout process. If something goes wrong and doesn't get a 200 header you get redirected to the cart.